# Why is this small loop failing?

Tags: php, arrays, count, compare, associative-array

My loop is as follows:

```
foreach( $user_answers_for_current_quiz as $question_id => $answer ) {
    if( $answer == $correct_answers[$question_id] ) {
        $score = $score + 1;
    }
}
```

The values getting supplied to this loop are as follows:-

```
$user_answers_for_current_quiz = [ 190 => "option_2, 183 => "option_1"];
$correct_answers = [ 183 = "option_1", 190 => "option_2" ];
$score = 0;
```

The strange behavior I'm observing is that in the first iteration, PHP can't figure out the value of

```
$correct_answers[ $question_id ]
```

and calculates it as `NULL`. However, in the second iteration it accurately calculates the value and updates the `$score`.

I checked PHP manual and found out that the array 'key' can be an integer. I'm not sure what's causing my loop to fail?

I've already spend over 3 hours trying to figure this out and would really appreciate if someone could point in the right direction. Thank you for your time in advance.

---

### ----------------+++ ADDENDUM +++-----------

Following are the values copied from actual run-time:

```
$user_answers_for_current_quiz = [ 62 => "2", 60 => "4", 57 => "2", 54 => "4", 52 => "3" ];
$correct_answers = [ 52 => "3", 54 => "4", 62 => "2", 60 => "4", 57 => "2" ];
```

for the code -

```
foreach( $user_answers_for_current_quiz as $question_id => $answer ) {
    if( $answer == $correct_answers[$question_id] ) {
        $score = $score + 1;
        print_r('Score'.$question_id." = ".  $score . "<br>");
    }
}
```

What the program prints is: `Score52 = 1`

I found out that the loop is unable to evaluate the 'if' condition; and I've no clue why. Would appreciate help.

Further Edit. Adding screenshot from xdebug:
[image]

Comment: You're missing a Quote after option_2. ```190 => "option_2", ...``` and a > after 183 in $correct_answers: ```183 => "option_1", ...```

Comment: Is that your actual code? There appear to be some typos in your array definitions.

Comment: You are missing a `>` and then also a `"` but after fixing that: https://3v4l.org/6qJ3M

Comment: After correcting syntax errors it will work fine. check this https://eval.in/807944

Comment: I apologies for the typos. I've updated the original question with values from actual run-time. Yet the code fails to work properly.

Comment: Okay! Issue solved. The error was with the small space getting added at the time of array creation. Notice the $correct_answers array and observe the space just before keys '54', '62', '60', '57'? That means, my keys were not right! PROBLEM SOLVED!

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect syntax in your question. At any rate, without the incorrect syntax your code should work. I tested this on my server and appears to work.

```
<?php


$user_answers_for_current_quiz = [ 190 => "option_2", 183 => "option_1"];
$correct_answers = [ 183 => "option_1", 190 => "option_2" ];
$score = 0;

foreach( $user_answers_for_current_quiz as $question_id => $answer ) {
    if( $answer == $correct_answers[$question_id] ) {
       $score = $score + 1;
        print_r('Score'.$question_id." = ".  $score . "<br>");
     }
}

 print_r('Last Score: '.  $score);


?>
```

This is the output:

[image: Output of debugging code]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach that you should be using:

```
$user_answers_for_current_quiz = [ 62 => "2", 60 => "4", 57 => "2", 54 => "4", 52 => "3" ];
$correct_answers = [ 52 => "3", 54 => "4", 62 => "2", 60 => "4", 57 => "2" ];

$score=sizeof(array_intersect_assoc($correct_answers,$user_answers_for_current_quiz));
echo $score;
// outputs: 5
```

`array_intersect_assoc()` retains all exact key-value pair matches regardless of their order/position in the arrays, `sizeof()` counts how many elements are retained.  This refines your method into a one-liner that doesn't need to conditionally overwrite/increment the `$score` variable on each iteration.